# Где написано про ООП в документации python

Tags: python, документация

Где в документации python находится раздел описывающий все возможности языка в ООП. Так например на большинстве сайтов про абстрактные классы нет ни слова, а они там появились. В документации смог найти только модуль отвечающий за это. Должно же быть в документации расписано как использовать классы и прочее

Comment: Смотреть в PEP, например: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/

Comment: Ну я так понимаю это в свежих версиях появилось, соответственно, нужно по свежим версиям изменения читать.

Comment: Абстрактные классы не вшиты жестко в ядро языка, а прикручены "сбоку" отдельным модулем. Ими можно не пользоваться. Про них можно почитать в документации по модулю [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

Comment: "Как использовать классы" - см. тут например: [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Про абстрактные классы там нет, т.к. это фактически опциональная возможность.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, конечно, озадачил. Мы каждый день читаем документацию, но мне вот не приходило в голову, что может возникнуть такой вопрос. Официальная документация - это не только описание модулей, но и туториалы. Попробуйте здесь почитать, [The  python tutorial 3.9.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#tutorial-index) и найти ответы на свои вопросы. Конкретно, пункт номер 9 затрагивает классы с общим описанием и прочим, например, то же наследование.